# How to determine size and position of span or relatively positioned element with Javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example, I want to draw submenu while its parent item is a `<span>` element. Can I determine the `<span>`'s dimensions and location on the fly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery provides a convenient way to get the dimensions or position of any element.

```
$myElement.offset()
```

will get you the location of the element, where you can then use `top` and `left`, and

```
$myElement.width()
```

will get you the element's width. `height()` acts the same way.

Comment: And what if I change top and left in the returned object? Will it affect original element?

Comment: No I have tested -- the changes affect only returned object, not location of original element....

Answer (score 1):

```
width =     $(this).parents("span:first").width()
height =    $(this).parents("span:first").height()

position

    var p =$(this).parents("span:first");
    var position = p.position();
    $("#myLabel").text( "left: " + position.left + ", top: " + position.top );
```

Comment: If you're, for example, into a function which is handling any event on the element (which parent you want to get) this is the element.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery you can get the element's width/height using:

```
$(this).parent().width();
$(this).parent().height();
```

And position:

```
$(this).parent().offset().left;
$(this).parent().offset().top;
```